# Honda civic 2018 loud suspension

Tags: honda, noise, civic, suspension

My Honda civic 2018 suspensions are loud when driving on roads that are not smooth and has small potholes or waves. If I drive slowly over potholes or wavy roads which would make the car go up and down, it doesn't make any noise.

The sound kind of looks like coming from the wheel hitting the bottom of the pothole after a free downward movement after car enters pothole.

What could be the cause of this?